# jQuery addClass attribute appears then disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list with 3 items, and I have made a jQuery click event to add a css class to it.
But when I click one of the items the class attribute is set but disapperas directly after.

Any ideas why?

Code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="home" href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="apps" href="apps.php">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a id="support" href="support.php">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').click(function (){
        $(this).addClass('btnActive');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:

When you follow a link, the entire DOM of the page is torn down and thrown away, and replaced by the DOM created by reading the HTML of the new page. So changes you make to the old DOM don't persist. If you want the "btnActive" class to be on the link when the page is loaded, you'll need to modify the HTML of the `home.php`, `apps.php`, and `support.php` pages accordingly.

E.g., for `home.php`:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="home" href="home.php" class="btnActive">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="apps" href="apps.php">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a id="support" href="support.php">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

...but for `apps.php`:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="home" href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="apps" href="apps.php" class="btnActive">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a id="support" href="support.php">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

Alternately, you could use JavaScript on page load to add the class based on the `location.href`, but really it's better to modify the HTML. But just for completeness, since you use the same value for the `id` of the link and the name of the page, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = location.href.replace(/.*\/([\w]+)\.php$/, '$1');
    if (id) {
        $("#" + id).addClass("btnActive");
    }
});
```

That isolates the name of the page from the URL (ignoring any path leading up to it, and stripping off the `.php` at the end), then uses it as an `id` and adds the class. Again, I don't recommend it, but with the URLs you quoted, it should work.

The following original answer was from before I realized (thanks to Rory) that you probably really do need to follow the link.

**Original Answer**:

Because you never tell the browser not to follow the link, so the page gets reloaded.

You can fix it by either doing `return false;` out of your event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').click(function (){
        $(this).addClass('btnActive');
        return false;  // <=== The new bit
    });
});
```

...or accepting the `event` argument and calling [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Accept the arg ---------v
    $('#home').click(function (event){
        // call the preventDefault
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('btnActive');
    });
});
```

`return false` in a jQuery event handler does two things:

1. Prevents the default action (in this case, following the link).
2. Stops the event propagating to ancestor elements.

`preventDefault` just does the first one.

Comment: I suspect this is the problem, but it seems like the click needs to happen. I think the actual logic of the code in the question is flawed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Hmmm, yes, looking at the markup I suspect you're right.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick answer! Marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the link to load "home.php":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('btnActive');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('btnActive');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
   <script>

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#home li').click(function() {
                        $('#home li').removeClass();
                        $(this).addClass('btnActive');
                    });
                });
            </script>


</head> 
<body> 
<ul id="home">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Apps</li>
    <li>Support</li>

</ul>
</body> 
</html>
```